# Backtracking and recursion in the n-queens problem (Python)

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I am writing a python class to find a solution to the 8 queens problem. How can I implement backtracking properly in my `solve` method? I think the recursion should work, however, the program stops after the solution is not found on the first try, and backtracking does not take place. All helper methods work properly.

```
EMPTY = 0
QUEEN = 1
RESTRICTED = 2

class Board:

    # initializes a 8x8 array
    def __init__ (self):
        self.board = [[EMPTY for x in range(8)] for y in range(8)]

    # pretty prints board
    def printBoard(self):
        for row in self.board:
            print(row)

    # places a queen on a board
    def placeQueen(self, x, y):
        # restricts row
        self.board[y] = [RESTRICTED for i in range(8)]

        # restricts column
        for row in self.board:
            row[x] = RESTRICTED

        # places queen
        self.board[y][x] = QUEEN

        self.fillDiagonal(x, y, 0, 0, -1, -1)   # restricts top left diagonal
        self.fillDiagonal(x, y, 7, 0, 1, -1)    # restructs top right diagonal
        self.fillDiagonal(x, y, 0, 7, -1, 1)    # restricts bottom left diagonal
        self.fillDiagonal(x, y, 7, 7, 1, 1)     # restricts bottom right diagonal

    # restricts a diagonal in a specified direction
    def fillDiagonal(self, x, y, xlim, ylim, xadd, yadd):
        if x != xlim and y != ylim:
            self.board[y + yadd][x + xadd] = RESTRICTED
            self.fillDiagonal(x + xadd, y + yadd, xlim, ylim, xadd, yadd)

    # recursively places queens such that no queen shares a row or
    # column with another queen, or in other words, no queen sits on a
    # restricted square. Should solve by backtracking until solution is found.
    def solve(self, queens):
        if queens == 8:
            return True

        for i in range(8):
            if self.board[i][queens] == EMPTY:
                self.placeQueen(queens, i)

                if self.solve(queens - 1):
                    return True

                self.board[i][queens] = RESTRICTED

        return False

b1 = Board()
b1.solve(7)
b1.printBoard()
```

Is my problem in the lack of a deep copy of the board before adding the queen, or is it just a lack of backtracking?

Comment: When I run this I just get a grid with `2` in all 64 points.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem -- when the board is filled in the first attempt to find a solution and none is found, all squares end up restricted.

Answer (score 1):

It's both: you have only one copy of the board in your entire program.  You fill it as best you can, until all squares are occupied or restricted; the search fails, and you return from `solve`.  With no mechanism to reset the board, your program ends.

Backtracking would make this simple, at the cost of multiple intermediate boards.  Instead of having a single board object ... make a deep copy, place the queen, mark the appropriate RESTRICTED squares, and pass that altered copy to the next level.  If you return with failure, let that copy evaporate naturally, being a local variable.